# Rails create associated records in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 tables:

project

```
has_many :answers
```

questions --> questions every project must answer

```
 has_many :answers
```

answers

```
belongs_to :project

belongs_to :question
```

So, when I create a new project, I would like to loop through the questions and create an answer record.  Then the user can see all of the questions and enter their answers.

In the project controller, I'm trying to create those records.
But, the following isn't working:

```
  before_create :create_answers

protected
def create_answers
  Questions.each do |i|
    self.answers.build  contact_id: self.contact_id, question_id: Question[i].id
  end
end
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Questions.each
```

Do:

```
Question.all.each
```

All that code will need to go in the Project model, not the ProjectsController.

And instead of:

```
Question[i].id
```

Do:

```
i.id
```

Make sure those attributes are `attr_accessible` as well.

All together:

```
before_create :build_answers

protected
def build_answers
  Question.all.each do |question|
    answers.build contact_id: contact_id, question_id: question.id
  end
end
```

And the attr_accessible bit:

```
attr_accessible :contact_id, :question_id
```